# I want to open and read the ubr file format

Tags: c++, vb6

Can anyone tell me, What is ubr file format?

And how to open the file? or is there any editor is there to read the file

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice, even if you didn't get the answer. Instead, improve your previous question.

Comment: Hi Yu hao, I did that, Still no response. It is in onhold status. Thats why i created the new questions.

Comment: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Cast your eye over this CodeProject question, it doesn't give you all the answers but it should tell you what it is [CodeProject Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/792545/What-is-ubr-file-format)
Failing that, Google came up with a few other sites when I put in "ubr file format".
Hope that helps.

Comment: This [Google](http://www.google.com) site seems pretty handy indeed! Bet they are going to get lots of visitors.